# How to apply Weights to Likert Scale Data for EFA in R?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, likert

I am part of a Survey Research Team and we are analysing Likert Scale Data.I would like to do a factor analysis for 9 items in the Survey,in order to find underlying structur. We also have Survey Design Weights for each person who took part in the Survey. The Data looks like this:

[image]

I know how to calculate weighted correlation Matrix in R using `cov.wt`, but how do I conduct factor analysis using `fa` from `psych` package with weights? Thank you Very Much in Advance !